# Print a variable number of digits of a double using printf

Tags: c, printf

Anyone knows if it is possible to use printf to print a VARIABLE number of digits?

The following line of code prints exactly 2:

```
printf("%.2lf", x);
```

but let's say I have a variable:

```
int precision = 2;
```

Is there a way to use it in printf to specify the number of digits?

Otherwise I will have to write a 'switch' or 'if' structure.

Thanks

Comment: Note : "%.2lf" print 2 digits AFTER the dot (3 will be printed 3.00)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is possible:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int precision = 3;
    float b = 6.412355;
    printf("%.*lf\n",precision,b);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: for the precision... never mind, your answer is great. thanks.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, you can do that easily -

```
int precision = 2;
printf("%.*lf", precision, x);
```

Comment: Thanks. this was exactly what I was hoping for. I've been using C for many years now, and somehow missed this little trick.

Comment: Useful if you want to do like digits=log10(something)+1 and then make filenames that will sort correctly, like to feed to ffmpeg and have them be in numerical order, which also becomes ASCII order.

Answer (score 4):

Yes: `printf("%*d", width, num)`:
see here: http://linux.die.net/man/3/printf

If you are using C++ you could use `std::cout` in combiation with `ios_base::precision()` :
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios_base/precision/

Answer (score 2):

If you use C++, you can use setprecision :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>      // std::setprecision

int main () {
    int precision = 2;
    double f =3.14159;

    std::cout << std::setprecision(precision) << f << '\n';
    ++precision;
    std::cout << std::setprecision(precision) << f << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

[Output](http://ideone.com/Ouh8Q7) :

```
3.1
3.14
```

You can read more about it [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setprecision)

Comment: ansi c - not c++. Thanks though.

Comment: @user2737130 Your question was tagged `C++` Please don't tag questions `C++` if you are using `C`, it leads to lots of answers that can't be used.